# WhenEvent to resolve NDSolve Singularity

Tags: differential-equations, singularity, event-detection

I'm trying to use NDSolve to solve the following ODE:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

k0r = 20;
k0l = 15;
sr = 1;
sl = 1;
a = 1/2;

p = 2 Sqrt[
    2/\[Pi]] (E^(-2 (t + x)^2 sl^2) k0l sl (1 - a) + 
      E^(-2 (t - x)^2 sr^2) k0r a sr + 
      E^(-(t + x)^2 sl^2 - (t - x)^2 sr^2) (k0l + k0r) Sqrt[a (1 - a)]
        Sqrt[sr sl] Cos[k0r (-t + x) + k0l (t + x)] - 
      2 E^(-(t + x)^2 sl^2 - (t - 
           x)^2 sr^2) (t (Sqrt[sl^5 sr] - Sqrt[sl sr^5]) + 
         x (Sqrt[sl^5 sr] + Sqrt[sl sr^5])) Sin[
        k0r (-t + x) + k0l (t + x)]) /. x -> xtraj1[t];
j = -2 Sqrt[
    2/\[Pi]] (E^(-2 (t + x)^2 sl^2) k0l sl (1 - a) - 
      E^(-2 (t - x)^2 sr^2) k0r a sr + 
      E^(-(t + x)^2 sl^2 - (t - x)^2 sr^2) (k0l - k0r)  Sqrt[
       a (1 - a)] Sqrt[sr sl] Cos[k0r (-t + x) + k0l (t + x)] - 
      2 E^(-(t + x)^2 sl^2 - (t - x)^2 sr^2) Sqrt[
       a (1 - a)] (x (Sqrt[sl^5 sr] - Sqrt[sl sr^5]) + 
         t (Sqrt[sl^5 sr] + Sqrt[sl sr^5])) Sin[
        k0r (-t + x) + k0l (t + x)]) /. x -> xtraj1[t];

V = j/p;

xtab = {0.25};

parasols := 
 NDSolve[{xtraj1'[t] == V, xtraj1[-2] == xtab}, xtraj1, {t, -2, 2}]

plot1 = Plot[Evaluate[{-xtraj1[t]} /. parasols], {t, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, Axes -> {False, False}, Frame -> True, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "CMU Serif Roman", 
    Black}, ImageSize -> 250, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin]]
```

This gives the error `NDSolve::ndsz: At t == -1.59699, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.` due to the obvious singularity in the denominator (p = 0). I've looked around for similar problems, and have found that it is possible to use `WhenEvent` to some effect in specifying singular points, but I haven't been able to successfully implement this into my problem, since I just want it to skip the point in the evaluation altogether. Is it possible to use `WhenEvent` to jump over the singularity, and continue running `NDSolve` past any singular points? (If you run the code below, you will see that the output trajectory runs off to infinity at the singular point, but I don't want this to occur -- the trajectory should just become horizontal at a single point (i.e. the velocity V = j/p becomes infinite), before becoming regular again.

Any help would be appreciated!